# Is there Android application to resolve intents when "activity not found to handle intent" by looking play store?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, resolver

When "activity not found to handle intent" error occurs, I need search in the Play Google app store appropriate application.
Is there way to find out application in play store by Intent, list them and display to the user? Then user can select one to download and install.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting concept but you're talking about going through roughly about a million apps and returning the apps that could fulfill the required intent. Of course it's not possible to do within your app and even if at least there is such functionality Google Play should implement it with an SDK.